# Multiply String perm

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

Using the following code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication5
    {
        class Program
        {
            public class PermutationFinder<T>
            {
                private T[] items;
                private Predicate<T[]> SuccessFunc;
                private bool success = false;
                private int itemsCount;

                public void Evaluate(T[] items, Predicate<T[]> SuccessFunc)
                {
                    this.items = items;
                    this.SuccessFunc = SuccessFunc;
                    this.itemsCount = items.Count();

                    Recurse(0);
                }

                private void Recurse(int index)
                {
                    T tmp;

                    if (index == itemsCount)
                        success = SuccessFunc(items);
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = index; i < itemsCount; i++)
                        {
                            tmp = items[index];
                            items[index] = items[i];
                            items[i] = tmp;

                            Recurse(index + 1);

                            if (success)
                                break;

                            tmp = items[index];
                            items[index] = items[i];
                            items[i] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                new Program().Start();
            }

            void Start()
            {
                string[] items = new string[9];
                items[0] = "1";
                items[1] = "2";
                items[2] = "3";
                items[3] = "5";
                items[4] = "6";
                items[5] = "7";
                items[6] = "8";
                items[7] = "9";
                items[8] = "0";
                new PermutationFinder<string>().Evaluate(items, Evaluate);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            public bool Evaluate(string[] items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}", items[0], items[1], items[2], items[3], items[4], items[5], items[6], items[7], items[8]));
                bool someCondition = false;

                if (someCondition)
                    return true;  // Tell the permutation finder to stop.

                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

I am able to generate permutations of the sequence "1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,0".
What I am looking for is a method to first convert each of the generated permutations into an integer, multiply the integer by two and then check if it is a permutation of the integer "1234567890". If it is, I want it to output the original integer. Does anyone know how I might go about achieving this?

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like you did not try anything yet ... you should! and then come back with a specific problem with what you tried, in case you do not succeed.